# Variable scope issue when accessing Firebase from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My current code for accessing my Firebase databse from Node.js looks roughly like this.:

```
var DesiredValue = "#";
ref.child("Example").once("value", function(snapshot) {
  DesiredValue = snapshot.val();
  console.log(DesiredValue)
});
console.log(DesiredValue)
```

It returns

```
>42
>#
```

where 42 is the value I want to grab, but I can't figure out how to retrieve it outside the scope of ref.child.(). I have tried the following which doesn't work.

```
var DesiredValue = ref.child("Example").once("value", function(snapshot) {
  var DesiredValue = snapshot.val();
  console.log(DesiredValue)
  return DesiredValue
});
console.log(DesiredValue)
```

All I want to do is use 42 in the remainder of the code. Based on what I have read there might be some way of using JavaScript's 'this' to achieve my goal, but I am worried of messing with global variables and think there must be an easier way?

Comment: you want to use this value in one flow of execution or sometime later aswell?
issue is your outside console.log calls before the once callback but it should print # first in the console then 42

Answer (score 0):

It's a callback you may use a promise, when it is resolved then you can use the value out of function or handle the value inside the callback, otherwise the code it's executed without waiting